# PHP Only Getting First Page of JSON Result

Tags: php, json, pagination

I am receiving JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "result": "SUCCESS",
  "message": {
    "totalResults": 371711,
    "resultsPerPage": 25,
    "page": 1,
    "data": [
      {
        "orderId": "8A62D2C05A",
        "clientOrderId": "8A62D2C05A",
        "shipCarrier": null,
        "shipMethod": null,
        "dateCreated": "2019-01-01 00:01:14",
        "dateUpdated": "2019-01-27 10:44:57",
        "orderType": "NEW_SALE",
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETE",
        "reviewStatus": "APPROVED",
        "totalAmount": "9.93",
        "avsResponse": null,
```

But I only get the 1st page of results, 25 items, with this code:

```
// curl stuff here
$rawresponse = curl_exec($curlSession);
$jrsp=json_decode($rawresponse,TRUE);
$result=$jrsp["result"];
$order_ct=$jrsp["message"]["totalResults"];
echo "Status $result for $order_ct orders.\n";
for ($i=0; $i<$order_ct; $i++) {
    $cust_id=$jrsp["message"]["data"][$i]["customerId"];
    $name=$jrsp["message"]["data"][$i]["name"];
    $ord_dt=$jrsp["message"]["data"][$i]["dateCreated"];
    $phone=$jrsp["message"]["data"][$i]["phoneNumber"];
    $ord_amnt=$jrsp["message"]["data"][$i]["totalAmount"];
    $item_ct=count($jrsp["message"]["data"][$i]["items"]);
    echo "ID:$cust_id Name: $name Date:$ord_dt Phone:$phone Amnt: $ord_amnt Item:$item_ct\n";
}
```

All of the initial echo says, "Status: SUCCESS for 371711 orders." as expected, but I only get the first 25 data items.  What do I need to do to get the other pages?

Comment: Depends entirely on the API you're calling. Sending a `page` param with a value of the page you want to view seems likely though. Where / how to send it? Not enough info.

Comment: `"resultsPerPage": 25` means that it only returns 25 results at a time, you have to call it in a loop, incrementing the `page` parameter, to get all the results. Getting all 371,711 results will probably take a while, do you really need them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "page" parameter in the api docs for the request, but I just found out from support the docs are incomplete. Jonnix and Barmar are both right. Thanks.  I do need a for $pages loop to get all results.